# Where is this verse attributed to the garuDa purANa found?

Tags: identification-request, garuda-purana, tulasi

I was reading excerpts from a book called sva-dharmAmR^ita-sindhu, which gives many instructions about worship and daily practice for devotees of the nimbArka sect. In one place, it talks about the importance of wearing tulasi beads, and [gives a variety of quotes in 3.36](https://archive.org/details/sva_dharmamrita_sindhu/page/n63/mode/2up) to support its position that this is obligatory or very meritorious. One of these is attributed to the garuDa purANa.

[image]

It says:

> गारुडे
> तुलसीकाष्ठमालाभिभूषितः पुण्यमाचरेत् ।
> पितॄणां देवतानां च कृतं कोटिगुणं कलौ ॥
>
> gAruDe -
> tulasIkAShThamAlAbhirbhUShitaH puNyamAcharet,
> pitR^INAM devatAnAM cha kR^itaM koTiguNaM kalau.

I assume this means that it comes from the garuDa purANa, since there are no other relevant texts with such a name. However, when I searched in the [text](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/corpustei/transformations/html/sa_garuDapurANa.htm), I could not find this verse. I also struggled to find any verses that were very similar with only a few differences. My question is **Where is this verse attributed to the garuDa purANa found?** I am aware that there are several different recensions of this purANa, so it may be a variant reading.

Comment: check out Skanda Purana, this particular verse is in that @Vedavedya

Comment: If you can find its location, can you post an answer?

Comment: https://www.hinduscriptures.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/71f_chapter_136.pdf  . Check out the 4th page 11th verse

Comment: Verse 11 there reads "... devatAnAM cha puNyaM koTiguNaM bhavet.", not the same text as above although it is similar. Maybe they mean very similar things in Sanskrit, thank you for the help. You should post a full answer below instead of commenting here so that I can approve it.

Comment: पठानतर is always accepted, I did not post an answer because its time consuming to research the exact chapter, but anyways it does exist inSkanda Purana.

Comment: To bring closure to this question, you can write a self [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer with due credit & accept it. @Vedavedya